# Unit of GeoPandas distance function after determining closest coastal line of a point

Tags: distance, geopandas, closest-distance

I am using this (I think working) code to find the distance of a lat/long point to some open source coast lines.

```
import os
import geopandas as gpd
import pandas as pd

os.chdir(r"C:\Users\gis_newbie\Downloads\natural_earth_vector\50m_physical")

# shapefile part of download from here https://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/
lines=gpd.read_file('ne_50m_coastline.shp')
# force CRS but I think it is already in this format
lines.to_crs("EPSG:4326")
lines.plot()

points_df = pd.DataFrame({'Latitude': [57.58125], 'Longitude': [-3.98848]}) # taken from lines data - so produced distance should be about 0

points = gpd.GeoDataFrame(points_df, geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(points_df.Longitude, points_df.Latitude, crs="EPSG:4326"))

for index, row in lines.iterrows():
    lines.at[index, 'distance'] = row['geometry'].distance(points.iloc[0]['geometry'])

lines = lines.sort_values(by=['distance'], ascending=True)
lines = lines.head(1) # minimum distance 
print(lines)
lines.plot()
```

I ensured that the data is in the same coordinate reference system. Despite lots of Google searches I am still not sure about the unit of GeoPandas' distance function. Is it degrees? Could one get it in km or meters without having to resort to using:

```
from math import radians, cos, sin, asin, sqrt

def haversine(lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2):
    """
    Calculate the great circle distance in kilometers between two points 
    on the earth (specified in decimal degrees)
    """
    # convert decimal degrees to radians 
    lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2 = map(radians, [lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2])

    # haversine formula 
    dlon = lon2 - lon1 
    dlat = lat2 - lat1 
    a = sin(dlat/2)**2 + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * sin(dlon/2)**2
    c = 2 * asin(sqrt(a)) 
    r = 6371 # Radius of earth in kilometers. Use 3956 for miles. Determines return value units.
    return c * r
```

Comment: Are you trying to find the distance to nearest coast?

Comment: yes - in other words given a land point I want to estimate distance to sea (as crow flies is good enough).

Comment: EPSG:4326 has length units in degrees, so the distance units are degrees. Your question is essentially how to get geopandas to calculate geodesic distances.

Comment: You can also reproject the coastline to an [aeqd projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Azimuthal_equidistant_projection) centred around the point of interest, which can be done on-the-fly with `lines.to_crs(f"+proj=aeqd +lat_0={pt.y} +lon_0={pt.x} +x_0=0 +y_0=0")` (assuming `pt = Point(-3.98848, 57.58125)`)

Comment: @MikeT - you put it very eloquently: "calculate geodesic distances" and also your other comment. would you mind posting an answer pls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70626218/how-to-find-the-nearest-linestring-to-a-point) in the meantime and adapted my somewhat reproducible code (see below). It appears to produce sensible results. What do you experts think?

```
import os
import geopandas as gpd
import pandas as pd

os.chdir(r"C:\Users\gis_newbie\Downloads\natural_earth_vector\50m_physical")

# shapefile part of download from here https://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/
lines=gpd.read_file('ne_50m_coastline.shp')
# force CRS but I think it is already in this format

lines.plot()

points_df = pd.DataFrame({'Latitude': [57.58125], 'Longitude': [-3.98848]}) # taken from lines data - so produced distance should be about 0
#points_df = pd.DataFrame({'Latitude': [51.509865],'Longitude': [-0.118092]}) # London

points = gpd.GeoDataFrame(points_df, geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(points_df.Longitude, points_df.Latitude, crs="epsg:4326"))

lines.to_crs("epsg:4326") #"EPSG:4326"

lines = lines.to_crs(lines.estimate_utm_crs())
points = points.to_crs(lines.crs)

for index, row in lines.iterrows():
    lines.at[index, 'distance'] = row['geometry'].distance(points.iloc[0]['geometry'])

lines = lines.sort_values(by=['distance'], ascending=True)
lines = lines.head(1) # minimum distance 
print(lines)
lines.plot()
```

Answer (score 1):

Reproject you data to a coordinate system with units in meters.

```
import geopandas as gpd

coast = gpd.read_file(r'/home/bera/Desktop/GIStest/sweden_outline_wgs84_4326.shp').to_crs(3006) #Replace 3006 with a crs fitting your needs
points = gpd.read_file(r'/home/bera/Desktop/GIStest/sweden_1k_random_points_4326.shp').to_crs(3006)

def closest_coastline(input_coast_df, input_point):
"""Finds the closest distance from one input point to the lines in an input line dataframe"""
    dist = round( min([input_point.distance(coastline) for coastline in input_coast_df.geometry])/1000, 0)
    return dist  

#closest_coastline(coast, points.at[0, 'geometry'])
#Out[55]: 16.0
```

[image]

Comment: You should not use 3857 for any distance measurement purposes, ever, for *any* reason. It is always wrong, and increases in wrongness as you get further from the Equator.

Comment: @vince what else to use please?

Comment: it is mainly UK/Europe

Comment: posted an answer - happy to delete - the code uses estimate_utm_crs and appears to produce sensible results in meters ...